# Hosting an MVC application as a virtual application within an MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, hosting

**Background**

The problem we're trying to solve is related to the sharing of framework components. With a typical approach where a website may contain multiple services, all sharing the root bin directory, deployment packages for various services using the same Framework components could overwrite each other.

For example:

- Service A and B know nothing of each other. Scripts, stylesheets and views reside in their own Areas folder.
- Service A uses Framework Component X v1.0. This has gone into BETA September.
- Service B uses Framework Component X v1.1. This has gone into BETA and LIVE in October.
- Due to delays, Service A is now ready for deployment to LIVE. The same package used for BETA (which has been signed-off against) has now overwritten Service A Framework Component X v1.1 as they share the same bin directory.

**Possible solutions**

1. Re-branch Service A from Master, update dependencies and recompile.
2. Host each service independently to the main 'portal' website, and handle cross-site requests.
3. Host each service as virtual applications

We would prefer to avoid recompiling code to update dependencies, so option 1 is least favorite.

Our estate is rather complex, and option 2 would be difficult from an infrastructure perspective. But we would consider.

Option 3 allows us to maintain a single host solution, and is preferred.

**My question**

1. Is it technically possible to host MVC applications within MVC applications as virtual applications, using IIS? If so, how is this achieved?
2. Is there an alternative which I've missed.